# How to test the significance of order of fixed features among various samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, trend

A practical statistic question was proposed here during my current research work.

- There are various sites across the country with identical features, which denote the content of 6 metal species (i.e., A, B, C, D, E, F ) in soil.
- The concentrations of those metals in soil have been already measured.
- For specific site *i*, the concentrations of those species might be in the order of A > B > C > D > E > F.
- To elucidate the general pattern of metal content across the country, I found that the order of  A > B > C > D > E > F were roughly shown for most sites.
- Is there any index to test the significance of such trends among various samples?

Any guide or comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the numbers for the metal content that each letter represents? or just the ranking?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the real measurement of those metals (unit in ug/g)  in soil for those sites

Comment: You might be able to specify the problem as: 1. Calculate the mean of metals across sites of interest. 2. Do all pairwise comparisons using either a t-test or wilcoxon.  (allows you to find the ranking basically).  I'm not sure that was your intent...

Comment: Maybe I have not clearly explained my issue. For each site, there would be a trend of metal concentrations (e.g., A > B > C > D > E > F). In most cases, similar trends  were observed among various sites. And thus, my question is how to test the statistic significance of such general trend.